# How compare variable to Array[i] in Python

Tags: python, list

I am learning python, one the the question I have is how can check if variable x is equal to array[i].  I am trying to use divide and conquer to find element in array

```
x = 12
arr = [12,31,33]

middle = len(arr)//2
print ("Find",x)
print ("Middle ", arr[middle])
print ("Middle Left",arr[middle] +1)
print ("Middle Right", arr[middle] -1)

if x == arr[middle]:
    print ("found it")
elif x == arr[middle] - 1 :
    print ("found on left")
elif x == arr[middle] + 1:
    print ("found on right")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `x == arr[i]` is exactly what you need. What's the error?

Comment: You should have been questioning why you get `32` and `30` printed when it's not in your list

Comment: shouldn't `arr[middle] - 1` read `arr[middle-1]`?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to find element at left/right based on index, you need to minus/add on index.

```
x = 12
arr = [12,31,33]

middle = len(arr)//2
print ("Find",x)
print ("Middle ", arr[middle])
print ("Middle Left",arr[middle + 1] )
print ("Middle Right", arr[middle -1])
if x == arr[middle]:
    print ("found it")
elif x == arr[middle - 1] :
    print ("found on left")
elif x == arr[middle + 1]:
    print ("found on right")
else:
```

Comment: @cricket_007 yes :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless your problem specifically says that you **must** use divide and conquer to do this, you could just use `.index(x)` to get its index - `i`.

So for your example:

```
x = 12
arr = [12,31,33]
```

then:

```
arr.index(x)
```

gives `0` for `i` (the `index`). This is much neater and unless you have a massive `list`, will be perfectly fast enough.

If it turns out you **must** write your own divide and conquer for this, then the place you are going wrong is when `indexing` from `arr` with `arr[middle]` and then `adding` and `subtracting` from **that value**. What you want to do instead, is `index` one further or one before with `arr[middle - 1]` or `arr[middle + 1]`.

Hopefully you can implement these changes to your code yourself if you don't want to use the much easier `.index()`.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a function like this?

```
arr = [12,31,33,31]

def position(array,key):

    # find all entries
    positions = [ind for ind,i in enumerate(array) if i==key]

    # return No match if nothing is found
    if not positions:
        return "No match!"

    # set mid to middle of array
    mid = len(arr) / 2

    # loop through all found elements and print
    for i in positions:

        if i < mid:
            where = "left"
        elif i > mid:
            where = "right"
        else:
            where = "mid"

        print("found {} on {}".format(key,where))


print(position(arr,31)) #  'found 31 on left \n found 31 on right'
print(position(arr,19)) # 'No match!'
```